# How to achieve active 4G LTE communication?

Tags: wireless, iot

I'm not sure if this is correct place to post this, if not PLEASE redirect me to the proper page, as this matter is quite pressing to me.

My entire day was spent researching different methods of inter-Arduino communication, and for my project, using 4G/LTE/LTE-M is clearly the route I need to take. However, I cannot find an answer to my problem:

I see a lot of information about how to continuously upload information to a IoT service/provider, or to a dashboard website. That's great. Problem is, I need an Arduino with a LTE shield to talk to another Arduino with a LTE shield. Suddenly the internet shuts down and I can find next to nothing about communicating between two Arduino's using LTE shields, much less keeping that connection active.

Of course this could be accomplished by uploading data to a IoT site via Arduino A, and retrieving stored information via Arduino B, but I'm afraid that will induce too much latency into my system. I need this to be as FAST as possible.

The module I have my eye set on currently is this one: https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/4g-gps-lte-wcdma-hspa-3g-gprs-shield-arduino-raspberry-pi-waspmote-tutorial/#step10

Is there a way to connect directly to another LTE device? How to I keep that connection always active? I know this question is a little broad, but I don't even know where to look! Internet connectivity is not my strong suit. From what I've gathered, I need to set up one Arduino as a server and the other as client. UDP may be the option I'm looking for, but I'm not totally sure. Every single tutorial/explanation I've seen is connecting directly to a webpage or other online service and NOT another LTE device.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You won't find any solution - because it is impossible; 4G LTE is not a peer-to-peer protocol.

Comment: What is your original design problem? What are your requirements?

Comment: @Milliways Then how do digital phone calls work? What about active connections like facetime? 
@ MikaelPatel I just need the most basic active connection between two LTE devices, whatever or however that might be.

Comment: @HavocRC Facetime and other peer2peer services use a server. Even you can use a server like Firebase to enable communication between the devices. Connecting between 4G to 4G is not possible at all. You may use Bluetooth/WiFi or RF for local communication.